# Calculate a new row with mean by one argument in the data frame

Tags: r, newrow

I want to calculate a new row (difference_mean_by_worker_id) with the mean (difference) by one argument (worker_id) in my existing data frame. The mean of the difference of every single worker_id should be the same in the new row.
Like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YskjF.jpg)

Thanks, Tim

Comment: Thats a very basic task. U should find plenty input on the web. I would recommend you use package data.table. Or build in tapply function.

Comment: Just `ave(df$difference,df$worker_id)`. Don't post images; rather copy/paste your dataset (or part of it) so everybody can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table);

# make the data
df = data.table(
  worker_id = c(111, 111, 222, 222),
  difference = c(5, 3, 5, 2)
);

# calculate mean difference
df_new = df[
  ,
  # make a new column called "difference_mean_by_worker_id" to be the mean of
  # "difference"
  "difference_mean_by_worked_id" := mean(x = difference),
  # grouped by worker_id
  by = "worker_id"
];

df_new;

       worker_id difference difference_mean_by_worked_id
1:       111          5                          4.0
2:       111          3                          4.0
3:       222          5                          3.5
4:       222          2                          3.5
```

This script calculates the mean for the distances in a group partitioned by `worker_id`. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your comments and your help :)